# Interference of EM Waves with Orbital Angular Momentum

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, angular-momentum

If you have two coherent collinear e-m beams of same frequency and polarization, but 180 degrees out of phase, they will destructively interfere.

If you introduce orbital angular momentum of L=3 (three revolutions per wavelength) to one beam and L=1 to the other beam, ceteris paribus, will they still destructively interfere in the exact same manner?

Comment: Depends a lot what is the state of your "orbital angular momentum L": a system with well define $L$ still has $2L+1$ states (Zeeman sublevels). What is their density matrix?

Comment: Not sure about density matrix but both OAM beams could be circularized polarized.

Maybe a better way to ask my question is:

Is there a way to generate light with OAM such that one could differentiate between beams (of same frequency) with different revolutions per wavelength, by destructive interference, where a beam with the same OAM would cancel a beam with exact same OAM, but not cancel a similar beam with a different OAM?   Thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand that you are talking about the OAM of _light_, not of a medium regular, $L=0$, light is supposed to go through.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you introduce L=3 to a beam of light, but I know if you give them repectively +1 and -1 for angular momentum there is no destructive interference; that is to say, the powers of the beams are simply additive.

Comment: yea, there's no such thing as light with L=3 in free space. The electromagnetic wave equation requires that the electric field components all have the same period as the wavelength. They can't have structure at one-third the wavelength. Also, in case readers don't know, +1 and -1 angular momentum mean the same thing as "right circular polarization" and "left circular polarization" respectively (or maybe vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

Free-propagating  light with non-zero orbital angular momentum is similar to transverse modes of  optical fiber higher than the central one. There will be no destructive interference because the transverse profiles of $L=1$ and $L=3$ light are orthogonal to each other. This should be true both clasically and quantum mechanically.